# Best way to communicate between Android app and C# application (text and images)

Tags: c#, android, networking

I am working on an C# application and Android App and I want to send informations like a button press from Android to C# and the C# application should send an image to Android.

Right now my solution is a simple TCP connection between Android (client) and application C# (server) and I convert the image to Base64 and send it to the Android app. I think this method is very inefficent and takes to much time.

I am very new to coding network applications, I will be very happy if someone can help me.

Comment: TCP you can send binary data if you add a header to data indicating number of bytes.  What is your ethernet speed (10M, 100M, 5G)?  What is the size of the files that you are sending?  You can easily calculate time of transfer.  Converting to Base64 takes time (and reverse) and will add time to the transfer.  But if it take milliseconds do you really care?  Before changing working code first do some calculations and determine if the changes will really speed up your application.

Comment: I think the speed will be about 100Mbit/s, it's only in the local network. Currently for a button press I send a string like "b:<button id, for example 1>" and the image "i:<base64 string>

Comment: As long as the receive end will know where the end of the binary data is you do not need to encode whe sending over TCP.  Since binary data can have any value between 0x00 to 0xFF you can't use an end character to determine when you have the last character so you need with binary data to put a byte count at the beginning of message so receive end can find the end of the data.  If you are sending a JPEG file of 100K bytes at 100M bits/sec  The time is 8 msec with no encoding.   Encoding will add to the size so it will be longer.  The real added time would be the time to encode and decode.